is there a way to open app from background in react-native
CallDetector.js
import CallDetectorManager from 'react-native-call-detection';
import CallLogs from 'react-native-call-log';
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

const detectCalls = () =\> {
console.log("Call detection started ::: ");
const callDetector = new CallDetectorManager(
(event, phoneNumber) => {
console.log("Event :: ", event);
if (event === 'Disconnected') {


//tried to open my app with deepLink
//This part is not opening my app from the background
Linking.openURL('myApp://call_add_edit').catch(err => console.error('Failed to open deep link:', err));

        console.log('Call disconnected with number: ', phoneNumber);
    },
    true, // if you want to read the phone number of the incoming call [ANDROID], otherwise false
    () => {
    },
    {
      title: 'Phone State Permission',
      message:
        'This app needs access to your phone state in order to react and/or to adapt to incoming calls.',
    }

);

return () => {
console.log("Calldetector desposed")
callDetector && callDetector.dispose();
};
}


export default detectCalls;

BackGroundTask
import BackgroundService from 'react-native-background-actions';
import BackgroundJob from 'react-native-background-actions';
import detectCalls from './CallDetector';

const sleep = time =\> new Promise(resolve =\> setTimeout(() =\> resolve(), time));

class BService {
constructor() {
this.Options = {
taskName: 'Demo',
taskTitle: 'Demo Running',
taskDesc: 'Demo',
taskIcon: {
name: 'ic_launcher',
type: 'mipmap',
},
color: '#ff00ff',
parameters: {
delay: 5000,
},
actions: '\["Exit"\]'
};

    }
    async VeryIntensiveTask(taskDataArguments) {
        const { delay } = taskDataArguments;
        await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    
            //Initiated background detection 
            detectCalls();
    
    
            var i = 0;
            for (let i = 0; BackgroundJob.isRunning(); i++) {
                message: "Success DOOD " + i
                // })
                console.log("Background task is running ")
                await sleep(delay);
            }
        });
    }
    Start() {
        BackgroundService.start(this.VeryIntensiveTask, this.Options);
    }
    Stop() {
        console.log("BackgroundService over ")
        BackgroundService.stop();
    }
    
    isBackGroundRunning() {
        return BackgroundService.isRunning();
    }

}
const BackgroudService = new BService();
export default BackgroudService;

Problem:
When the app is in the background, the Linking.openURL('myApp://call_add_edit') does not open the app or navigate to the specific screen.
However, it works perfectly when the app is in the foreground.
What I've Tried:
Ensuring that deep linking is set up correctly, which works in the foreground.
Using react-native-background-actions to run the call detection logic in the background.
Additional Information:
Package name: com.myApp
Deep link URL scheme: myApp://
Target screen: call_add_edit
1--> I've tried to implement the native libraries but it's the same as before, it'll work on foreground but not on background.
2-->I've tried by editing the package's native code of react-native-call-detection and tried to open app directly from their by passing new Intent. but still it's the same ? foreground : background.
Question:
How can I properly open my React Native app from the background and navigate to the call_add_edit screen using deep linking when a call is detected? Is there a specific approach or additional configuration required to achieve this?
or it's possible that the way i'm doing it is also a wrong way but please share the another solution then Thanks!!
i'm so cooked!!!!
